# Why does my app not reflect my custom theme, which is based on ext-theme-gray?

Tags: extjs, themes

I used Sencha Cmd to generate workspace, app, package, custom theme, and edited my custom theme package.json to extend ext-theme-gray.

But when I refresh the app and build the package, my app does not reflect the gray theme.

I should mention that the ExtJS 4.2 docs on themes mentions the standard theme folders should be in my workspace packages folder by now, but they were not, though I followed the instructions to generate workspace/package exactly.

So I copied the ext-theme-gray folder to my packages folder and then did app refresh and package build.

But my UI still does not reflect the gray theme.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

I needed to specify the custom theme here:

extApps/usx/.sencha/app/sencha.cfg

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify your new/custom theme on your project's config file found on `.sencha/app/sencha.cfg`.

```
app.theme=my-custom-theme
#app.theme=ext-theme-classic
```

Then execute `sencha app refresh` from your project's root directory.